# Strange behavior of WhenEvent, a bug?

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

I really feel sorry that I have asked too many questions on this forum about DAE. But I'm indeed facing a lot of problems on this topic and `NDSolve`. Once again I would like to use my favorite example to show my observation on the strange behavior of `WhenEvent`. This system is about a water heating /cooling system in a house with a simple control strategy.

1. The first equations is an energy conservation equations with the outdoor temperature $t_o$ (from some data source), room temperature $t_r$, the heat capacity of the house $C_{eff}$ and its loss factor $R$.
2. The second equation describes the water heating / cooling system and its heat flux $q$: the heat flux is equal to the water inlet and outlet temperature difference ($t_{in} - t_{out}$) times the volume flow rate $v_F$ and water heat capacity.
3. The third equation determines the water outlet temperature given the room temperature $t_r$, inlet temperature $t_{in}$ and the water volume flow rate $v_F$.
4. The fourth equation represents a simple P-controller.

Since we would want both heating and cooling, we need 2 different water inlet temperatures $t_{in}$ for heating and cooling modes: 30 and 16 °C. Moreover, the target room temperatures $t_{r,0}$ are also different in these 2 modes: 21 and 24 °C, respectively. For simplicity, let's suppose that cooling mode is switched on if the outdoor temperature $t_o$ is higher than 20 °C, otherwise the heating mode is switched on.

With these assumptions in mind, we can setup the equations. NDSolve runs to the end without any error message, though the computational speed is not very satisfying.

```
li = Import["http://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/old_data/nsrdb/1991-2005/data/tmy3/725958TYA.CSV"];
to = With[{data = Drop[Drop[li, 1][[All, 32]], 1]}, 
  Interpolation[
   Join[{{0, (data[[1]] + data[[-1]])/2}}, 
    Transpose[{Range[8760] - 0.5, 
      data}], {{8760, (data[[1]] + data[[-1]])/2}}]]];

Ceff = 50 25 3;
R = 0.005
(* equations *)
eq0 = {100 q[tau] - (tr[tau] - to[tau]) / R == Ceff der[tr[tau]],
   q[tau] - (tin[tau] - tout[tau]) vF[tau] 7/6. == 0,
   tout[tau] - tr[tau] - (tin[tau] - tr[tau]) Exp[-0.9/(7/6 Max[vF[tau], $MachineEpsilon] 0.22)] == 0,
   vF[tau] - Min[Max[0, (20 + mode[tau] 20 (tr0[tau] - tr[tau]))], 100] == 0,
   WhenEvent[to[tau] > 20, {mode[tau] -> -1, tin[tau] -> 16, tr0[tau] -> 24}],
   WhenEvent[to[tau] < 20, {mode[tau] -> 1, tin[tau] -> 30, tr0[tau] -> 21}]};
(* initial conditions *)
ic0 = Join[(FindRoot[Thread[Cases[eq0, _Equal][[All, 1]] == 0] /. {mode[tau] -> 1, 
   tin[tau] -> 30, tr0[tau] -> 21, der[i__] -> 0, tau -> 0}, 
   Transpose[{{q[0], tr[0], tout[0], vF[0]}, {3577, 20, 20, 42}}]] /. Rule -> Equal), 
   {mode[0] == 1, tin[0] == 30, tr0[0] == 21}]

AbsoluteTiming[
 solfull0 = 
   Module[{time = 1.}, 
    Flatten[Monitor[
      NDSolve[Join[eq0 /. {der[i__] :> D[i, tau]}, ic0], {q, tr, tout,
         vF, mode, tin, tr0}, {tau, 0, 8760},
       StepMonitor :> (time = tau), 
       DiscreteVariables -> {Element[mode, {-1, 1}], 
         Element[tin, {16, 30}], Element[tr0, {21, 24}]}], time]]];]
(* {252.195, Null} *)
```

If we take a closer look at the results, we will see some strange things happening. Let's extract the water inlet temperature from the results.

```
list = Transpose[{Flatten[(tin /. solfull0)["Grid"]], Flatten[(tin /. solfull0)["ValuesOnGrid"]]}];
Take[list, 20]
(* {{0., 30.}, 
    {2123.12, 30.}, {2123.12, 16.}, {2123.12, 16.}, {2123.12, 16.}, 
    {2129.05, 16.}, {2129.05, 30.}, {2129.05, 30.}, {2129.05, 16.}, 
    {2171.81, 16.}, {2171.81, 16.}, 
    {2176.89, 16.}, {2176.89, 30.}, 
    {2196.97, 30.}, {2196.97, 16.}, 
    {2200.92, 16.}, {2200.92, 30.}, {2200.92, 30.}, {2200.92, 16.}, 
    {2219.5, 16.}} *)
```

We can see that at `tau == 2123.12` the `tin` jumping from 30 to 16 (after that the second event was triggered twice? Why does that happen?), which is OK since the `tin` becomes 16 as desired. But at `tau == 2129.05`, the `tin` jumped from 16 to 30 back and forth and eventually landed at 16, which was not right, since the `to` is going from above 20 to below 20 at this point and the `tin` is supposed to be 30.

[image]

If we plot the whole `tin` with `to` together, we can see that this jumping back and forth behavior happens quite often and the results are not right.

```
Partition[
 Show[Plot[{to[tau], 20}, {tau, 24 #, 24 (# + 5)}, 
     GridLines -> {Table[i, {i, 24 #, 24 (# + 5), 24}], Automatic}, 
     FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {Table[i, {i, 24 #, 24 (# + 5), 24}], 
        None}}, PlotRange -> {{24 #, 24 (# + 5)}, {-5, 35}}, 
     Frame -> True], 
    ListLinePlot[list, PlotRange -> {{24 #, 24 (# + 5)}, {-5, 35}}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Red, Dotted}]] & /@ Range[88, 303, 5], 4]
```

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why this happens and how can I resolve this issue? It seems like a bug to me...

**EDIT**

Here is part of the data that can also produce the wrong results.

```
li1 = {{0, 6.`}, {1, 9.`}, {2, 7.`}, {3, 2.`}, {4, 1.`}, {5, 6.`}, {6,
     10.`}, {7, 13.`}, {8, 15.6`}, {9, 17.5`}, {10, 20.`}, {11, 
    22.`}, {12, 23.`}, {13, 24.`}, {14, 25.1`}, {15, 26.`}, {16, 
    26.`}, {17, 26.`}, {18, 23.`}, {19, 20.`}, {20, 17.2`}, {21, 
    14.4`}, {22, 13.`}, {23, 10.`}, {24, 8.`}, {25, 6.`}, {26, 
    5.`}, {27, 5.`}, {28, 3.`}, {29, 7.`}, {30, 12.`}, {31, 
    16.`}, {32, 19.`}, {33, 22.`}, {34, 25.`}, {35, 27.`}, {36, 
    28.`}, {37, 30.`}, {38, 28.`}, {39, 27.8`}, {40, 28.`}, {41, 
    26.`}, {42, 26.`}, {43, 23.`}, {44, 21.`}, {45, 21.`}, {46, 
    19.8`}, {47, 17.6`}, {48, 15.6`}};


(* the rest remains the same *)
to = Interpolation[li1];
Ceff = 50 25 3;
eq0 = {100 q[tau] - 200 (tr[tau] - tae[tau]) == Ceff der[tr[tau]],
   q[tau] - (tin[tau] - tout[tau]) vF[tau] 7/6. == 0,
   tout[tau] - 
     tr[tau] - (tin[tau] - 
        tr[tau]) Exp[-0.9/(7/6 Max[vF[tau], $MachineEpsilon] 0.22)] ==
     0,
   vF[tau] - 
     Min[Max[0, (20 + mode[tau] 20 (tr0[tau] - tr[tau]))], 100] == 0,
   WhenEvent[
    tae[tau] > 20, {mode[tau] -> -1, tin[tau] -> 16, 
     tr0[tau] -> 24}],
   WhenEvent[
    tae[tau] < 20, {mode[tau] -> 1, tin[tau] -> 30, 
     tr0[tau] -> 21}]};
ic0 = Join[(FindRoot[
      Thread[Cases[eq0, _Equal][[All, 1]] == 0] /. {mode[tau] -> 1, 
        tin[tau] -> 30,
        tr0[tau] -> 21, tae -> to, der[i__] -> 0, tau -> 0}, 
      Transpose[{{q[0], tr[0], tout[0], vF[0]}, {3577, 20, 20, 42}}], 
      MaxIterations -> 10000] /. Rule -> Equal), {mode[0] == 1, 
    tin[0] == 30, tr0[0] == 21}];
AbsoluteTiming[
 solfull0 = 
   Module[{time = 1., dtime = 0.}, 
    Flatten[Monitor[
      NDSolve[Join[eq0 /. {der[i__] :> D[i, tau], tae -> to}, 
        ic0], {q, tr, tout, vF, tin, mode, tr0}, {tau, 0, 48}, 
       MaxSteps -> \[Infinity], 
       StepMonitor :> (dtime = tau - time; time = tau), 
       DiscreteVariables -> {Element[mode, {-1, 1}], 
         Element[tr0, {21, 24}], Element[tin, {16, 30}]}], 
      Column[{time, dtime}]]]];]
list = Transpose[{Flatten[(tin /. solfull0)[
     "Grid"]], (tin /. solfull0)["ValuesOnGrid"]}];
Show[Plot[{to[tau], 20}, {tau, 0, 48}, PlotLegends -> {"to", 20}], 
 ListLinePlot[list, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dotted}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"tin"}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, the question will be more attractive if you can simplify it more. Simplifying the sample as much as possible also helps you to locate the problem. For example, is it necessary to import the `li` from external links? The "jump" already shows up in the first 20 elements of `list`. Is the issue reproducable with a small part of `li`?

Comment: I am taking a wild guess here: Have a look at `FullForm[Take[list, 20]]`. My guess is that the number are not at the same position but in fact very small time steps apart. Could it be that once the transition below 20 is made the event kind of oscillates between values? I am not sure if if helps but [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html#2095119923) is a similar example in the documentation.

Comment: @xzczd I've added part of the data in li that can also produce the strange result.

Comment: @user21 I've added a smaller dataset that produces the same behavior. `FullForm[list]` gives me `List[List[0.`, 30.`], List[10.`, 30.`], List[10.`, 16.`], List[19.`, \
16.`], List[19.`, 30.`], List[19.`, 30.`], List[19.`, 16.`], \
List[32.333333333333336`, 16.`], List[32.333333333333336`, 16.`], \
List[45.880460509023024`, 16.`], List[45.880460509023024`, 30.`], \
List[48.`, 30.`]]`. It looks like that very small time step is not the reason for this behavior? It is in fact very interesting why the example in the documentation works and my example doesn't.

Comment: BTW I think that this strange behavior might also make the calculation slower, since after each event being triggered, the system needs to be reinitialized. This behavior might cause more reinitialization than necessary.

Comment: The following seems to resolve the issue: `WhenEvent[
 tae[tau] > 
  20, {mode[tau], tin[tau], tr0[tau]} -> {-1, 16, 24}], WhenEvent[
 tae[tau] < 20, {mode[tau], tin[tau], tr0[tau]} -> {1, 30, 21}]` so this seems to be related to the sequential event actions in your original code. You may check **Possible Issues** -> **Event Actions** for a simpler example.

Comment: @407PZ In older versions there was an example with a controller. Use `WhenEvent[
 to[tau] > 
  20.01, {mode[tau], tin[tau], tr0[tau]} -> {-1, 16, 24}], WhenEvent[
 to[tau] < 19.99, {mode[tau], tin[tau], tr0[tau]} -> {1, 30, 21}]`